# Image saving as tmp in database in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

**Blade File**

```xml
<form action="{{route('sproduct.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      class="w-75 mx-auto mt-5 mb-5">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group mt-2 mb-2">
        <label for="formgroupexampleinput">Select Product</label>
        <select name="products" id="products">
            <option>Select Product</option>
            @foreach ($products as $product)
                <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->title}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
        <label for="formgroupexampleinput">Display Images</label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-primary w-25" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Fuction**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasfile('file')) {
        foreach ($request->file as $file) {
            $fileExt = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_name = "img_".rand(123456,999999). "." .$fileExt;
            $destination_path = public_path('/uploads/products_images/display_images');
            $file->move($destination_path, $image_name);
            $image = new Image();
            $image->image = $file;
            $image->product_id = $request->products;
            $image->save();
        }
        return "done";
    }
}
```

**Question**
hi, I am trying to add images to my images table but the image is saving as a tmp file in the database but saving as a jpg in the given folder. I don't know the solution to this. Please let me know why this is happening and how to fix it.
Thankyou in Advance.

Comment: `dd($file)` and see what attributes it has.  you might find your answer.

Comment: Why are you trying to save the `File` object to your database? Don't you want to save the location of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**miken`enter code here`** in **comment** told me I needed to save the name of the file.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasfile('file')){
        foreach ($request->file as $file) {
            $fileExt = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_name = "img_".rand(123456,999999). "." .$fileExt;
            $destination_path = public_path('/uploads/products_images/display_images');
            $file->move($destination_path, $image_name);
            $image = new Image();
            $image->image = $image_name;
            $image->product_id = $request->products;
            $image->save();
        }
        return "done";
    }
}
```